# Can't query Oracle tables from R - "Could not SQLExecDirect" error

Tags: r, oracle

I created a connection:

```
library(RODBC)

pswd <- readline("Input Password: ")

channel<-odbcConnect (dsn="dsn",uid="uid",pwd=pswd,believeNRows=FALSE)
```

And I am able to get a list of tables

```
tables <- sqlTables(channel, schema="SYSADM")
```

But when I try to query one of the tables

```
query <- "select * from SYSADM.TABLE1"
dataframe <- sqlQuery(channel,query)
```

I get:

> "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'SELECT * FROM \"TABLE1\"'"

I do have access to this table and am able to query it using Toad.
What could be the issue?

Comment: dataframe <- sqlQuery(channel,"select * from TABLE1")

Comment: Getting the same error

Answer (score -1):

Kindly make a change as follows and then try below queries:

```
tables <- sqlTables(channel, schema='SYSADM')
```

**Queries:**

```
 dataframe <- sqlQuery(channel,"select * from SYSADM.TABLE1")
```

Or

```
query <- paste("select * from SYSADM.TABLE1")

dataframe <- sqlQuery(channel,"select * from SYSADM.TABLE1")
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you Harshil, but that is the same thing I was trying to do.

Comment: So it's working, right? If the answer is helpful to solve your issue, then upvote and/or accept the answer. That'll be helpful to the new visitors.

Comment: Sorry but when I said it is the same thing I've tried,it means that doesn't help. You literally provided the same code I have in the question.

Comment: Are you sure your table is not empty? Because that might be a reason too.

Comment: It is not, I am able to query it via Toad. Could it be that there are some administrative privileges enforced only at the R (RODBC) level?

Comment: R version 3.4.1 Oracle 11g

Comment: I just tried your code in my local system and it worked. It must be some privilege issue.